# uWSGI logging format unification

Tags: logging, uwsgi

I'm attempting to unify the log format of my uwsgi instance. Currently there's three different types of log items:

- `Sun Sep  2 17:31:00 2012 - spawned uWSGI worker 10 (pid: 2958, cores: 8)`
- `(DEBUG) 2012-09-02 17:31:01,526 - getFileKeys_rpc called`
- `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/dispatch.py", line 13, in application
  obj = discovery(env)
  File "src/dispatch.py", line 23, in discovery
  ret_obj = {"return":dispatch(method,env)}
  File "src/dispatch.py", line 32, in dispatch
  raise Exception("test")
  Exception: test`

The first is an error spawned by uWSGI internally (I have the --log-date option set). The second is from the logging module, which has `logging.basicConfig(format='(%(levelname)s) %(asctime)s - %(message)s')` set. The final one is an uncaught exception.

I understand that the uncaught exception probably can't be formatted, but is there some way of having uwsgi use the logging module for its internal logs? Or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use uWSGI 1.3 and set the 'python' logger, with

--logger python

Comment: damn, is there an easy way to get that through pip or do I have to wait for it to become the stable branch?